# Documentation on passing parameters to event url

Tags: eventbrite

I am working on developing an integration between EventBrite and a CRM platform.  In order to sync data back to the CRM platform I would like to pass a query string variable of the customer id to the EventBrite event url and have that data passed back to me when I query the API.  Is this possible?  If so is there documentation on what query string variables are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an endpoint right now that supports this.

I would assume that you'd want to pass an email address as a unique identifier, and see all the associated tickets/registrations with that attendee.

Thanks for the feedback, we'll add this to our backlog, but it isn't something on our roadmap.

Comment: I was hoping for something like what SurveyMonkey has http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-track-respondents-using-a-unique-ID 

The problem with email is most CRMs do not use email as a unique identifier.